# how to four table manage in infinite scrolling spreadsheet

Tags: jquery, css, html, spreadsheet

I am trying to 4 html table in one spreadsheet and each table horizontal and vertically scroll individual used in query spreadsheet please suggest me.

Currently I have manage one table in one spreadsheet, I am trying to table to set on height and width but it is not working please suggest me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var win = $(window);
  var doc = $(document);

  // Each time the user scrolls
  win.scroll(function() {
    // Vertical end reached?
    if (doc.height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
      // New row
      var tr = $('<tr />').append($('<th />')).appendTo($('#spreadsheet'));
      // Current number of columns to create
      var n_cols = $('#spreadsheet tr:first-child th').length;
      for (var i = 0; i < n_cols; ++i)
        tr.append($('<td />'));
    }

    // Horizontal end reached?
    if (doc.width() - win.width() == win.scrollLeft()) {
      // New column in the heading row
      $('#spreadsheet tr:first-child').append($('<th />'));
      // New column in each row
      $('#spreadsheet tr:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
        $(this).append($('<td />'));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dsfd">
  <table id="spreadsheet">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>

      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Are you talking about exporting to excel?

Comment: @mplungjan no, please my update code...

Comment: @mplungjan not exporting excel but data is render is same like row and column formate but multiple table

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make a [mcve] from it

Comment: I suspect the confusion is that you're saying "4 tables in one *spreadsheet*" - assuming you mean "in one *page*" this still doesn't make sense as when you scroll the page $(window).scroll which of the tables is supposed to increase? All of them? Unless they're lined up in 4 columns, this will be a terrible effect - but you also have horizontal scroll adding columns. Then you mention fixed height/width which seems to defeat the purpose of scrolling on the window.